For EPIC FHIR I want to download documents to get more information about labs and treatments. Checked API's But didn't find one
Wanted to get more data by downloading the document to fetch more data about patient and get them downloaded and parse them two build clear doctor view.
I have been tried multiple endpoints from EPIC FHIR for the resolution but unable to find one, Can anybody suggest one which I can use for my purpose./

If you go to https://fhir.epic.com/ you can see which FHIR resource types they support on their API. This includes DiagnosticReport and Observation for the lab results you’re looking for and CarePlan and Medication* resources for the treatments.
